# Create dataframe using formats defined in seperate dataframe template

Tags: r, dataframe

I am creating multiple dataframes, and I want the columns in each of them to be the same type as that specified in a blank dataframe template I have created

For example I have a blank template

```
template <- data.frame(
  char = character(),
  int = integer(),
  fac1 = factor(levels = c('level1', 'level2', 'level3')),
  fac2 = factor(levels = c('level4', 'level5')),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

And then I want to create a few dataframes but want to keep the columns in the format of the template (i.e. char to be a character, fac2 to be a factor with two levels 'level4' and 'level5')

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  char = c('a', 'b'),
  int = c(1,2),
  fac1 = c('level2', 'level1'),
  fac2 = c('level4', 'level4')
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  char = c('c', 'd'),
  int = c(3,4),
  fac1 = c('level3', 'level4'),
  fac2 = c('level5', 'level4')
)
```

I can obviosuly specify the columns types when I am creating `df1` and `df2`, but I want to avoid having to type out the same thing muliple times, and if for example the levels change in a factor I only want to change it in one place.

If an value is created in one of the factors which is not a level (e.g. 'level 4' in 'fac1' in 'df2' above, then it should be replaced by NA when converting to the correct format

Comment: If you check the `str(template)`, `char` is not `character`.  You need `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you can just post-process your data frame:

```
df_template <- function(...) {
  df <- data.frame(...)
  df$char <- as.character(df$char)
  df$int  <- as.integer(df$int)
  df$fac1 <- factor(df$fac1, levels = c('level1', 'level2', 'level3'))
  df$fac2 <- factor(df$fac2, levels = c('level4', 'level5'))
  df
}
```

Answer (score 3):

We can create a function that checks the `type` of each column of the template  and use a `as.*` function to coerce the corresponding column of the relevant `data.frame` to the to the relevant `type`.

We make an exception for `factors` (as their `type` is `integer`) and we assign the relevant `levels` to the new modified column.

`Map` takes the column of template and input by pair, and the output (a `list`) is then converted to `data.frame`.

```
format_df <- function(df,template) {
  as.data.frame(
    Map(function(x,y) {
      if(is.factor(x))
        factor(y,levels(x))
      else
        match.fun(paste0("as.",typeof(x)))(y)
        # or `class<-`(y,class(x)) , same effect for given example
    },template,df),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}


df1b <- format_df(df1,template)
# char int   fac1   fac2
# 1    a   1 level2 level4
# 2    b   2 level1 level4

str(df1b)
# 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  4 variables:
# $ char: chr  "a" "b"
# $ int : int  1 2
# $ fac1: Factor w/ 3 levels "level1","level2",..: 2 1
# $ fac2: Factor w/ 2 levels "level4","level5": 1 1
```

Note the `level5` in output.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a template, you can create kind of a constructor for your specific data.frame.

For example,

```
.TEMPLATE <- data.frame(
  char = character(),
  int = integer(),
  fac1 = factor(levels = c('level1', 'level2', 'level3')),
  fac2 = factor(levels = c('level4', 'level5')),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

df_constructor <- function(...) {
  df <- as.data.frame(...)
  within(df, {
    char <- as(char, class(.TEMPLATE$char)),
    int <- as(int, class(.TEMPLATE$int)),
    fac1 <- factor(fac1, levels(.TEMPLATE$fac1)),
    fac1 <- factor(fac1, levels(.TEMPLATE$fac2)),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  })
}
```

`vapply` function has the FUN.VALUE argument where you can pass a template used to build the return value. But I am not sure if `vapply` works well with data.frames.